# Insert data from DataTable to database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, datatable

What is the easiest and most efficient way to insert data from a DataTable into a SQL Server database table?  For what it's worth, the DataTable and the database table have matching columns.

What I am doing is transferring data from one database to another (separate instances, so I will be using my application as the intermediate "receiver/sender" of data).  I can easily populate a DataTable with a SqlDataAdapater.Fill() call from the source database table.  But I'm trying to find the most proficient way to send that DataTable's data to the final destination database table.

Any suggestions/advice/opinions are much appreciated.

*EDIT: the destination database table already exists.*

Comment: An existing DB table or a new one?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  It's an existing DB table.

Comment: Use DataAdapter together with DataSet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), particularly the [overload of the `WriteToServer` method that takes a `DataTable` as a parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx).

If you want to be even *more* efficient, and you don't have the requirement to materialize the entire table into a `DataSet` (or, you can process the contents as you move them in a forward-only manner), then use the [overload of `WriteToServer` that takes an `IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) run your query using the [`ExecuteReader` method on the `SqlCommand` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) instead of using a [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879f39d8.aspx) to load the entire table into memory.

Comment: Your first option seems simple enough, but your second option has really intrigued me.  The DataTable could have potentially 20,000 rows of wide data.  So it is very tempting to be able to skirt around that.

Comment: @Surfer513: If your data is that big (vertically or horizontally), then using an `IDataReader` with the `SqlBulkCopy` class is the way to go, you're skirting the transaction log on SQL Server, not sending an update for each individual row (it's part of one operation) and you aren't materializing the entire set of data in memory before pushing it back out.  You'll see gains using the `SqlBulkCopy` class with the `DataTable` (I recommend you try that first), but even bigger gains using the `IDataReader` (try that after you get it working with the `DataTable`)

Comment: after reading that second link you posted about the second option, it seems like that is very feasible.  My question to you is, obviously it is memory conscious and efficient, but is it PERFORMANCE efficient, as in processing time?  Or would SqlBulkCopy class with the WriteToServer taking a DataTable parameter beat it out?  I'm more concerned about processing time, as this Win Svc will be running on pretty hefty servers with gobs of memory (hopefully =) ).

Comment: @Surfer513: Ultimately, the answer is test, test, test, but think of it like this; with the `DataTable`, you have to read the entire contents from one server into memory, so that's one pass over all of your data, then whether or not you use `SqlBulkCopy` or a `SqlDataAdapter`, you have to do another pass over that data.  With a `SqlBulkCopy` instance *and* an `IDataReader` you're only ever going to do one pass through the data, the `SqlBulkCopy` instance will pull all the data it needs from the `IDataReader`, it never has to do another pass.

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius.

Comment: @Surfer513: How much of a performance improvement did you see?